# Reading binary file using Win32 API

Tags: winapi

I am trying to read a binary file and write to a different place.

But the code displays only the first bit - "MZ".  According to MSDN, "CreateFile and ReadFile
 do not use parameters to differentiate between text and binary file types." But my code works fine with txt files.

```
                HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( L"C:\\in.exe", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL); 
                if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
                { 
                    char lpBuffer[2000] = "";
                    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
                    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

                    HANDLE hTest = CreateFile(L"D:\\out.exe", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL);  
                    ReadFile(hFile, lpBuffer, sizeof(lpBuffer), &dwBytesRead, NULL); 
                    WriteFile(hTest, &lpBuffer[0], dwBytesRead, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

                    CloseHandle(hFile); 
                    CloseHandle(hTest);
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean `the code displays only the first bit - "MZ"`? Executable files are not printable, if you're just trying to send it to `cout` or something.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I mean, when I debug, the value of "lpbuffer" only displays "MZ"

Comment: Binary files can contain zeroes.  The debugger, however, displays the buffer as if it were a null-terminated string, so it shows only characters up to the first zero.

Comment: Assuming that your debugger is Visual Studio, you can add a watch and provide additional information to control the display of the data. You can see the entire buffer by entering `lpBuffer,2000`. Also note that `lpBuffer` is an **array**, not a **pointer**, so your prefix is misleading. Also, do get into the habit of checking return values. Depending on your version and edition of Visual Studio you can have it analyze the code for failure to check return values.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following code I get "2000 MZÉ 0".

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\cppConsole.exe",
    GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    char lpBuffer[2000] = "";
    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    ReadFile(hFile, lpBuffer, sizeof(lpBuffer), &dwBytesRead, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    std::wcout << dwBytesRead << L' ' << lpBuffer << L' ' << (int)lpBuffer[3] << L'\n';
}
```

Note that it says dwBytesRead is 2000, in other words 2000 bytes were read. The reason it says that lpBuffer is "MZÉ" is because there is a null following it. So if you looked at lpBuffer as a string then you would get only a portion of the data.

Answer (score -3):

This is silly... Now I know why.

```
                char lpBuffer[2000] = "";
```

When it comes to binary file, the size of buffer is much bigger. I changed 2000 to 10000, now it works! 
Although the lpBuffer appears only "MZ", it will proceed anyway.